# Disable dropdown list in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to disable the dropdownlist from javascript. I used below code to disable.
        I want to check weather `'LabResultRegistration_FltDataEntryPointV'` value is empty or not when the form loads. If it has value the user does not allow to change `'LabResultRegistration_FltDataEntryPointV'`(disable) `'LabResultRegistration_FltDataEntryPointV'`).

For new entries it should be enabled.

```js
    window.onload = function() {
      var dep = document.getElementById("LabResultRegistration_FltDataEntryPointV");
      if (dep.value != "" || dep.value == undefined) {
        dep.disabled == true;
      } else {
        dep.disabled == false;
      }
    }
```

```html
<input type='text' 
       data-role='combobox'  
       data-text-field='DisplayName' 
       data-value-field='DisplayName' 
       id='LabResultRegistration_FltDataEntryPointV'
       onblur='LabResultRegistration_FltDataEntryPointV_onblur(event)'
       onchange='LabResultRegistration_FltDataEntryPointV_onchange(event)' 
       data-filter='contains' data-bind='value:data.DataEntryPointRef.Value,events: { open: onComboLoad, change:cmbChange, filtering:OnFilter }'                     
       maxlength=50 required name='Data entry point' 
       validationMessage= 'Data entry point is mandatory' />
```

But, it is not working.
    after **dep.disabled = true;**
    it is terminating from IF condition.
    Could anyone help me to fix it?
    Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please create a snippet (click the [<>] button in the editor and show all relevant code and html - we do not know now if `LabResultRegistration_FltDataEntryPointV` is a form field as the .value suggests . One other thing is to use `window.onload=LabRegResult_Load` instead of the inline body onload

Comment: You are not adding an else case where you should also enable dropdown

Comment: The `value` of a form field is never null so that's possibly the problem. (There might be other issues, can't know without seeing the HTML and console output.)

Comment: Do you have a form? Can you post the html of the element? Where the value comes from?

Comment: Do a console.log(document.getElementById("LabResultRegistration_FltDataEntryPointV").value); and see the value to see what value is when it's "null". It might be undefined or "", etc..

Comment: Yes, I used window.onload=LabRe‌​gResult_Load. But, it is checking if condition, but, not going to end }
if (dep != null){        
    document.getElementById("LabResultRegistration_FltDataEntryPointV").disabled = true;    
        }
I meant after checking condition it is going to next 'disabled'. but, not going to end brace '}'.

Comment: Please check my answer and add sufficient tml if my answer is not useful

Comment: Yes, I went through your answer. I did some changes in my code, But, How can I add my code to show you. Coz, AddComment has limited access. :(

Comment: Update the QUESTION. Do not add comments with code. Also it seems like you are using KENDO, why not tag the question with that too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have

```
window.onload=function() {
  var dep=document.getElementById("LabResultRegistration_FltDataEntryPointV");
  dep.disabled = dep.value != "";
}
```

but note that disabled fields are not sent to the server so you might want to duplicate the value in a hidden field or replace the select with a hidden field and a span:

```
window.onload=function() {
  var dep=document.getElementById("LabResultRegistration_FltDataEntryPointV");
  if (dep.value != "") {
    var span = document.getElementById("depSpan");
    span.innerHTML=dep.value;
    dep.style.display="none"; // hide
  }
}
```

using the additional

```
<span id="depSpan"></span>
```

If you are using Kendo, which it seems you are, you may need to do

```
var combo = $("#LabResultRegistration_FltDataEntryPointV"").data("kendoComboBox")
combo.readonly(combo.value=="");
```

Comment: if(dep.value != "" || dep.value == undefined){
      dep.disabled == true;
  }
  else{
      dep.disabled == false;
  }
}
it is not executing after  dep.disabled == true; after this it is skipping condition.

Comment: <input type='text'  data-role='combobox'  data-text-field='DisplayName' data-value-field='DisplayName' id='LabResultRegistration_FltDataEntryPointV' onblur='LabResultRegistration_FltDataEntryPointV_onblur(event)' onchange='LabResultRegistration_FltDataEntryPointV_onchange(event)' data-filter='contains' data-bind='value:data.DataEntryPointRef.Value,events: { open: onComboLoad, change:cmbChange, filtering:OnFilter }' 

       maxlength=50 required name='Data entry point' validationMessage= 'Data entry point is mandatory' />
 This is the field I want to disable.

Comment: If the ID of the rendered combobox is still `LabResultRegistr‌​ation_FltDataEntryPoi‌​ntV` and it has a value, use the updated code I gave you. If not we need to look in the [Kendo documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox) see my update